# Monitoring SQL performance and load

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a C# based application that performs different operations on an SQL Server 2008 R2 based database instance.

This is the scenario:

- There is a single SQL instance.
- There are multiple databases (around 50).
- The application perform different operations including IO and CPU operations (on the SQL server).
- The code is multi-threaded which means multiple threads access the SQL instance at once.
- The SQL server *is not* on the same computer as the application server.

Now, I have a problem where the SQL becomes the bottleneck (both IO and CPU) and what I would like is to be able to have a process thread check if the SQL is "too occupied" before it starts a new process and if it is too occupied, postpone the process for some time and check again later.

It is possible to receive, using a simple/basic SQL query, information regarding the current load of the SQL instance? CPU load like usage percentage? IO load like disk r/w queue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Gilad.

Comment: Have you used SQL Profiler to identify what is causing the bottleneck? It might be better to optimise the work the sever is doing than to manage the load from your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance is always a multi faceted area. How have you determined that SQL is the bottleneck? Have you tried better indexes and also optimising your queries?

To answer your question though, its actually quite easy to query performance monitor counters and SQL Server installs a heap of counters when the product is installed.

Go to the start menu and run 'perfmon', then add in some counters to look at in the various SQL Server categories or even the more basic memory and CPU categories.

From that, you can see what counters to monitor. You can use external tools to monitor the counters to see if they exceed thresholds, or write the collected data to a SQL table, file, or even monitor the counters via code.

See the following posts for more information.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2008/11/07/querying-perfmon-data-from-sql.aspx

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1039

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2006/12/dba-101-using-perfmon-for-sql-performance-tuning/

Also, the System.Diagnostics namespace contains performance counter classes to monitor/alter this stuff via code.

Comment: The SQL is the bottleneck, the question is not how to improve the SQL but now to monitor. I can't use system counters as the Application is on a different machine and there is a major security issue accessing performance counters from a distant machine. I need a method that uses SQL queries only.

Comment: @Gilad: You could query the table sys.dm_os_performance_counters on the sql instance.